# How to remove padding between image and text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm getting a big white space between an image and the text below it.

[image]

The code has no widget between the image and the text.

```java
children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset('assets/images/maggie.png'),
              RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  children: <TextSpan>[
                    TextSpan(
                        text: 'About Maggie McPherson',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 24.0,
                          height: 3.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
```

I like the padding above the image and on the sides but there's too much padding below the image. Reading the [Image class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html) documentation I don't see any mention of default padding.

Comment: Your image doesn't have a white space, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `height: 3.0` from your `TextStyle()`

Comment: That worked. I don't understand why `height 3.0` added a small space below my header and a big space above it. I assumed that the added spaces would be equal above and below the header.

Answer (score 0):

Check Padding because of image using:

```cs
Image(
  image: AssetImage("assets/fb_icon.png"),
  color: Colors.red,
  colorBlendMode: BlendMode.multiply,
),
```

#### Try this after you check above

Use BoxFit.cover to see effect

```cs
Image(
  image: AssetImage("assets/fb_icon.png"),
  width: 180.0,
  height: 250.0,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove **height: 3.0** and wrap **Image** with **padding**.

**Solution:**

```
children: <Widget> [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30,left: 30,right: 30),
        child: Image.asset('assets/images/maggie.png'),
      ),
      RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          children: <TextSpan>[
            TextSpan(
                text: 'About Maggie McPherson',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.black,
                )),
          ],
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to remove `height: 3.0` and instead put a `SizedBox(height: 5)` between the header `RichText` widget and and the text `RichText` widget. `height: 3.0` added a small space below the header and a big space above the header.